# I have created a contact form 7 in my wordpress app , but when someone type Hindi context , received email content shows blank context in email body

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a contact form 7 in my wordpress app , but when someone type Hindi context , received email content shows blank context in email body

, . , . something like that received in email instead of real context